# spark scala read config file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a config file in my hdfs containing the columnnames to be selected from json file

schema of json

```
  { 
    a:string
    b:int
    c struct
     {
       id: string
       count : integer
     }
  }


 Config.txt 
 "a","b","c.id"
```

In the code

```
 val df = sqlcontext.read.json("jsonfile"
 val config_file = "Config.txt"
 val config = scala.io.Source.fromFile(config_file).mkString
 val df_contents=df.selectExpr(config)
 df_contents.printSchema()
 df_cust_att_contents.show()
```

I am getting error in df.selectExpr(config) . Its not recognised. Its throwing error. How to pass the column names from config file to selectExpr. Please help

Answer (score 0):

`selectExpr` needs one argument per one column. You are trying to put all columns in one argument.

Try:

```
df.selectExpr(config.replaceAll("\"", "").split(","): _*)
```

Comment: @gayathri So please accept it and give it up vote :)

Comment: @gayathri Not this, it has zero score ;)